"Eigenvalue" in Statistical Mechanics
In Pathria's "Statistical Mechanics", 3rd ed., on page 41, he is going over a discussion of the canonical ensemble and lays out the following definitions:
$$
\mathcal{N}=\sum_rn_r \quad \quad \sum_rn_rE_r=\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{N}U
$$
Where,

$\mathcal{N}$ is the ensemble of identical systems, presumably meaning the number of identically prepared systems.
$n_r$ denotes the number of systems at any time $t$, having energy $E_r$.
$\mathcal{E}$ is the total shared energy of those systems, which presumably doesn't mean anything physical.
$U$ is the average energy per system in the ensemble, corresponding to statistical (and thermal) equilibrium.
$E_r$ denotes the "energy eigenvalues" of the systems.

I recall studying Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors in undergrad (I'm an EE, so apologies that I haven't been as exposed to them as much as a Physics major), and I also know how they are interpreted in QM, but what does it mean here, in the context of statistical mechanics? Would someone be able to provide a reference or explanation?
For clarity, I am able to follow Pathria's derivation of the canonical ensemble, so that's not my main question here. Just wondering about his use of the term "energy eigenvalues".
As a sidebar, I'm curious about the physical difference between this setup and Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics, where it looks to generate the same function. In particular I am looking at the section of the Wikipedia article that uses $i$ to represent a particular state, rather than the set of states consistent with $E_i$. In this case $E_r$'s equivalent would be the $i$-th energy level, $N$ is the total number of particles, and $\langle N_i \rangle$ refers to the average number of particles in state $i$.
Seems that the major difference is considering an ensemble of systems (Pathria) vs. considering a single system and the distribution of energy of the particles inside it (Maxwell-Boltzmann).
